# Add a link to Law.SE to the Help Center?

Tags: discussion

From the Help Center, on ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Laws - Answers on laws, regulations and licencing should not be taken as legally binding - we're security professionals so deal with legal issues, but this site is not a law site.

Could we perhaps add a link to [law.stackexchange.com](https://law.stackexchange.com/), to help direct people to a site where they will get better help than here, and not run such a high risk of being closed as off topic?

Comment: FYI, I opened a meta.Law question to make sure they agree with what's been said here: http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/531/8903

Answer (score 9, accepted):

UPDATE:

I went and [asked on meta.Law.SE](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/531/8903) and got this response from two of their mods:

> You should feel free to migrate posts that ask legal questions without asking for legal advice.
>
> Of those remaining: Many questions asking for legal advice can be "genericized" so as to ask for legal information.

So if we can encourage users to transform "what should I do?" questions into "what does the law say?" questions, then they would be happy to have them migrated.

---

As @WhiteWinterWolf also said, this clip from [their help page](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says it all:

> Law Stack Exchange is for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law.
>
> ...
>
> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter. These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer.

So that's pretty clear that Law.SE is not a free lawyer service; they want to discuss general points about the legal system, famous historical court rulings, trade tips about being a legal professional, etc; they don't give a dime about your problems.

Many of the questions like this that I've seen on security.SE should really be closed with "You need to hire a lawyer dude" -- they won't be any more welcome on Law.SE than they are here. Although a few are more like legal thought-experiments that may be interesting to others.

I would avoid putting explicit reference to Law.SE in our help page out of fear that we generate a flood of free lawyer requests. Rather, let high rep users vote to close or flag for mod migration as usual.

Comment: I think some legal questions might be very suitable for Law.SE, but you are probably right that some are not. So I agree that community/moderator discretion might be a good idea here.

Answer (score 9):

While a good idea (IMHO) in principle, I think this should be checked with Law.SE Meta before doing anything as this goes into some grey area about what is on-topic there.

Quoting Law.SE [help page](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please don't ask questions seeking legal advice on a specific matter.
>   These are off-topic for Law Stack Exchange.

I'm not sure whether in practice such questions are tolerated on their site and where exactly they put the limit between generic and specific matter (it's like here: we are OK to answer security questions or provide some help for an audit, we are not OK to break systems on request or provide free audits).

I have the impression that Law.SE is not a law site either, but a site *about* laws which is not the same thing.

I would not feel comfortable in officially redirecting people coming with questions they would consider out-of-topic. On the other side, one can see that they even have an active [hacking](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacking) tag, so maybe with an appropriate wording to avoid polluting their site this would do the trick?

Otherwise, the easiest way will be to proceed as we do now: if a question is a really good fit for Law.SE (and off-topic here), just request it's migration through the flagging system (you will need to use the *In need of moderator attention* since the Law.SE website is not part of the post migration list).

For instance [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/132974/32746) and [there](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/128521/32746) are two recent questions which have been recently migrated.

Comment: Very good points. Thanks!